# This is about the ads using admob for displaying the ads in the real mobile device

Tags: java, android

I developed an app and i want to add the advertisements. If i add this below key i can able to get the adds.
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712

But if i use this below key which was create by me i am not getting the add

ca-app-pub-9914256985225098/9374773560
    ca-app-pub-9914256985225098/9235172760

It is getting the error like the below
W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0

can any one please give me some solution

Comment: What is the question? If you use a key invent by yourself, you don't receive and add... that's correct.

Comment: "create by me" how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what google says

"It could be that you have only recently created a new Ad Unit ID and requesting for live ads. It could take a few hours for ads to start getting served if that is that case. If you are receiving test ads then your implementation is fine. Just wait a few hours and see if you are able to receive live ads then. If not, can send us your Ad Unit ID for us to look into."